# How to check if an element exists in a column, and then insert a square with text in a certain cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which filters a list and copies the values filtered (isn't the important part),

From that list I need to check if certain values exist, for example "Gestión de dato maestro". If this cell exists then I want to create a square in some cell with the text "Gestión de dato maestro".

I tried using Vlookup in vba but it didnt work

List I want to work on

[image]

The output i need

[image]

Comment: Did you try using "Find"?

Comment: Links: [Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) and [Shapes.AddTextbox Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shapes-addtextbox-method-excel).

Comment: Do you want to find it in filtered list or in whole data? Post some data rather than screenshot so that viewer can copy and paste data to worksheet and do some R&D on those data.

Comment: I want to find it in the filtered list, i filter, copy and paste the filtered list on a diferent sheet, if i find certain value y i want to create a box with text on some cell i need to choose. @Harun24HR

Comment: Is the square that you wish to insert the little dropdown square with the triangle, which enables users to choose values that should be inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this, I'm using cell A20 of the same sheet of the list as my "input value to check" address, you can change it right there on `Cells(20, 1)`

```
Sub createDataShapes()

Dim rng As Range
Dim shp, rect As Shape


Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(20, 1).Value)

If Not IsNull(rng.Value) Then
        For Each shp In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes
            shp.Delete
        Next shp
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape msoShapeRectangle, 100, 100, 100, 100
    Set rect = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    rect.TextFrame.Characters.Text = rng.Value
End If


End Sub
```